# Error 1241 Operand should contain 2 column(s)

Tags: mysql, operand

My query : http://pastebin.com/8c2rLrRk

In this 3rd case 2nd when condition is causing the issue, if i comment that then query is running well. So pls let me know where the loophole in this syntax.

Comment: You would get a faster answer by reducing your code to a minimal example and adding it to your code instead of 300 lines of code in a pastebin. While trying to provide your minimal example you would probably have found the answer yourself. Anyway: `WHEN ((COUNT(bookedseats.seat_num),0)<(` should probably not have a `,0` there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the solution. Issue with (COUNT(bookedseats.seat_num),0 is syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error line: IFNULL(COUNT(blockedseats.seatNo),0)
We can't club count and ifnull functions.